# In Javascript why can't I replace x => f(f)(x) by f(f)?

Tags: javascript, lambda, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I was trying to implement the Y combinator in Javascript.

I managed to implement the following:

```
const y0 = gen => (f => f(f))( f => gen( x => f(f)(x) ) );
const factorial0 = y0( fact => n => n<=2 ? n : n * fact(n-1) );
console.log(factorial0(5));
// 120
```

It works well.

Then I was considering the expression `x => f(f)(x)`.

My understanding is that an expression `x => g(x)` is equivalent to `g`.  Applying any `y` to `x => g(x)` evaluates to `g(y)`, while applying `y` to `g` also evaluates to `g(y)`.

So I replaced `x => f(f)(x)` by `f(f)`.

```
const y = gen => (f => f(f))( f => gen( f(f) ) );
const factorial = y( fact => n => n<=2 ? n : n * fact(n-1) );
console.log(factorial(5));
// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

But this version crashes with a stack overflow.

So what is the difference between `x => f(f)(x)` and `f(f)` so that the one works and the other crashes.

Comment: Because strict evaluation.

Comment: @Bergi Three words - I call this a lazy explanation :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that those 2 expressions are not exactly the same.

On one hand `x => f(f)(x)` - this creates a new function literal (so it is not invoked right away - it is invoked only when this function is called)

On the other hand `f(f)` - this in Javascript is a an expression that calls the `f` function. So it results in a stack overflow in your case.

Comment: Or in other words, `x => f(f)(x)` is the lazy version of `f(f)`. Since Javascript is strictly evaluated, we have to wrap patterns like `f(f)` into a lambda to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: I think this is the crux of the problem.  The expression  x=>f(f)(x)  delays the evaluation of f(f) until x is provided.

Answer (score 4):

Well

```
x => f(f)(x)
```

is a function taking one parameter, `x`. When the function is called, it in turn calls the function `f`, passing a reference to `f` as a parameter. Function `f` returns another function, and then that is invoked, with `x` passed as a parameter.

In old-school syntax, it's

```
function(x) {
  return f(f)(x);
}
```

That's significantly different than just `f(f)` by itself. That's just an invocation of the function "f", with "f" passed as a parameter.

So both `x => f(f)(x)` and `f(f)` are **expressions**, but they represent significantly different semantics. The value of the first is a reference to a function; the expression itself *doesn't do anything else* — in particular, the function `f()` is not called. The value of `f(f)` is whatever function `f()` returns when called — that expression *does* do something, that being whatever function `f()` does.